# Extra query parameters

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

It is possible to pass extra query parameters from the web application that calls the B2C policy.

With MSAL:
AuthenticationParameters.extraQueryParameters

```
{
  extraQueryParameters: { ['utm_source']: window.location.origin },
}
```

This will add "&utm_source=something.com" in the URL

> mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_signup_signin&**utm_source=something.com**&.....

My problem is that as soon as I jump to a second page, or click on the Sign Up link, you completely loose all of these extra query parameters.

i.e You click on SignUp, the url is now

> mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?local=signup&csrf_token=123456&tx=StateProperties=123456&p=B2C_1A_signup_signin

How can I keep these extra query params?

How can I also keep these params when you go to a Social IDP then back on the social confirmation page?

Comment: Why not just resolve them in the initial page? Then it doesn’t matter what the user does next.

Comment: @JasSuri that's what we ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve the query parameters in the initial page. Then it doesn’t matter what the user does next.